# Template carrega apenas em um view

Tags: php, laravel

Boa noite!

Criei um diretório chamado layouts e dentro dele um template (template.blade.php) para usar em minhas views sempre que necessário, porém o mesmo carrega apenas em um view cujo nome é index.blade.php, já em outra view chamada addOrcamento.blade.php não carrega, segue o código

Tamplate.blade.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{'assets/css/estiloHeader.css'}}">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid" >
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavBar">
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand">Oficina <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog logo-small" style="color:#FFF;font-size:22px"></span></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavBar">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li><a href="{{route('addOrcamento')}}">Cadastrar Orçamento</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <article>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    @yield('content')
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <footer>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                 Todos os direitos reservados || Oficina 2.0
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{'assets/js/query-3.1.1.min.js'}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.blade.php

```html
@extends('layouts.template')
@section('title','orçamentos')
    
@section('content')
<table class="table-reponsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>CLIENTE</th>
                    <th>VENDEDOR</th>
                    <th>DESCRICAO</th>
                    <th>DATA E HORA</th>
                    <th>VALOR</th>
                    <th>AÇÃO</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach ($data as $item)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item->cliente}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item->vendedor}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item->descricao}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item->data_hora}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item->valor_orcamento}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{route('editOrcamento',['id'=>$item->id])}}" class="btn-danger btn-sm">Editar</a> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </table>
@endsection
```

addOrcamento.blade.php

```html
@extends('layouts.template')
@section('title','adiciona orcamento')
    
@section('content')
<form method="POST">
    @csrf
    <label for="cliente">Cliente</label>
    <input type="text" name="cliente" id="cliente"><br/><br/>

    <label for="vendedor">vendedor</label>
    <input type="text" name="vendedor" id="vendedor"><br/><br/>

    <label for="descricao">descricao</label>
    <input type="text" name="descricao" id="descricao"><br/><br/>

    <label for="data_hora">data e hora</label>
    <input type="date" name="data_hora" id="data_hora"><br/><br/>

    <label for="valor_orcamento">valor do orcamento</label>
    <input type="text" name="valor_orcamento" id="valor_orcamento"><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="cadastrar">
</form>
@endsection
```

Comment: Verificou o log se algum erro foi gerado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer carregar duas views simultaneamente você precisa criar elas como nome diferente @section('content') e @section('content1'), então você pode adicionar 2 includes.

Se você quer carregar uma outra dependendo de onde o usuário clicar você deve arrumar isto no controller. Por exemplo no trecho:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavBar">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="{{route('addOrcamento')}}">Cadastrar Orçamento</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Você pode colocar a rota como `<a href="{{route('addOrcamento.index')}}">` e na função index do controle de addOrcamento você coloca um `return view ('caminho da sua view aqui')`
Assim este mesmo content pode ser alterado dependendo do click.